# Webscraping with Selenium- how to pick the right selectors

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have trouble locating the proper selectors. Working on a practise case where the task is to search for certain images and then download all of them.

Before Imgur I tried Flickr for my project, but could not get past the pop up where I wanted to reject the cookies by clicking the "Reject All" button. I thought with browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rejectAll") I should be able to reach the button.

There´s something I'm missing when trying to use these scraping options. Grateful for any help!

Flickr Example
https://www.flickr.com/

<a class="rejectAll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 questions you have asked. Answering one of the question, i.e. clicking on <kbd>Reject All</kbd> button on this website - https://www.flickr.com/

If you inspect the DOM and notice the HTML, <kbd>Reject All</kbd> button is wrapped within an IFRAME, in such case, you need to switch into the IFRAME and then try to click on Reject All button.

[image]

**Refer the below code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.flickr.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Switch into the IFRAME within which the Reject All button exists
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='truste_popframe']")))
# Click Reject All button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Reject All']"))).click()
# Click Close button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Close']"))).click()

# Below line will come out of the IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn. I figured Flickr was just another example of me missing something basic in my approach, since none worked out. I will read up on IFRAME and study your solution. I did go through selenium read the docs, but there was no such example. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint received. I split my q's into 2 separate ones and will resubmit the second one. The flickr question is solved.